# Showing error on empty input field ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to enable/disable a form button based on if there are any characters in both the of the text input fields, but for some reason the state lengths are rendering an error with my conditional, despite when I log the state it shows up.

**Error:**

```
const isEnabled = this.state.subject.length > 0 && this.state.emails.length > 0; 
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

**Full Code:**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class EmailAnnotationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            csrf: '',
            subject: '',
            emails: '',
            comment: ''
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
        this.input = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.subject.length) // renders correct value => 0
        this.setState({subject: this.props.title });
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleClearForm() {
        this.setState({
            csrf: '',
            subject: '',
            emails: '',
            comment: ''
        })
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event) {
        var emailSubject;  
        {
            this.state.subject ? emailSubject = this.state.subject : emailSubject = this.props.title
        }; //

        const body = {
            subject: emailSubject,
            emails: this.state.emails,
            comment: this.state.comment
        };

        event.preventDefault();
        var route = `${API_ROOT}` + '/api/annotation/' + this.props.annotationId + '/share/email';
        fetch(route,
            {
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                compress: false,
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': this.props.csrf,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                this.handleClearForm();
                this.props.shareFlashMessage('success');
                this.setState({'flash': 'success'});
                this.props.closeShareModal(false);
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.props.shareFlashMessage('error');
                this.setState({'flash': 'error'});
            });
    }


    render() {
        var emailSubject;  
        {
            this.state.subject 
                ? 
            emailSubject = this.state.subject 
                : 
            emailSubject = this.props.title
        };

        console.log(this.state) // csrf: '', subject: undefined, emails: '', comment: ''
        console.log(this.state.subject) // renders undefined

        const isEnabled = this.state.subject.length > 0 && this.state.emails.length > 0; //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

        return (
            <div className="annotation-footer__share-form-email">
                <form action={"/api/annotation/" + this.props.annotationId + "/share/email"} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} name="annotationEmailShare" id="share-email-form">
                    <div className="input-group annotation-footer__share-form-email-inputs">
                        <p><b>Subject:</b></p>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.title} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/><br />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group annotation-footer__share-form-email-inputs">
                        <p><b>Emails (Comma separate each email address):</b></p>
                        <input type="text" name="emails" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/><br />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group annotation-footer__share-form-email-inputs">
                        <p><b>Additional Comment (Optional):</b></p>
                        <textarea name="comment" rows="4" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></textarea><br />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" disabled={!isEnabled}>Send Email</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `this.props.title` is undefined.

To solve the issue, put the check on `this.props.title` value, and update the state only if it has a valid value. Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(this.props.title)
    this.setState({ subject: this.props.title });
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Instead of updating `subject` with props value in `didMount` method, do it in constructor itself, Like this:

```
this.state = {
  csrf: '',
  subject: props.title || '',
  emails: '',
  comment: ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and answer!